# Merge sort algorithm does not work (python)

Tags: python, list, sorting, mergesort

I was trying to do the merge sort algorithm but I get no output seems like is getting stuck on an inifinity loop

I am trying to return a list of numbers sorted in descendent order but only with the even numbers here is the code:

```
def leer_vector(lis,n):
    for x in range(n):
        lis.append(int(input("Ingrese el dato: ")))
    return lis

cd = int(input("Ingrese la cantidad de datos: "))
v1 = []
v2 = []
v3 = []
leer_vector(v1,cd)
leer_vector(v2,cd)

v3 = v1 + v2

def merge_sort(arr):
    if len(arr) > 1:
        leftarr = arr[:len(arr)//2]
        rightarr = arr[len(arr)//2:]

        merge_sort(leftarr)
        merge_sort(rightarr)

        i = 0
        j = 0
        k = 0

        while i < len(leftarr) and j < len(rightarr):
            if leftarr[i] > rightarr[j] and leftarr[i] % 2 == 0:
                arr[k] = leftarr[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                if rightarr[j] % 2 == 0:
                    arr[k] = rightarr[j]
                    j += 1
 

            k += 1
        
        while i < len(leftarr):
            if leftarr[i] % 2  == 0:
                arr[k] = leftarr[i]
                i += 1 
                k += 1
        
        while j < len(rightarr):
            if rightarr[j] % 2 == 0:
                arr[k] =  rightarr[j]
                j += 1
                k += 1

merge_sort(v3)
print(v3)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not find the bug for you here; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre].

Comment: "I am trying to return a list of numbers sorted in descendent order but only with the even numbers " Did you try writing code that **just** sorts the numbers, and **then** selecting only the even numbers from the result?

Comment: Hint: how many different places does the code say `i += 1`? How many different places does it say `j += 1`? Does that seem right?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel that sound good but I would like know why this one does not work out

Comment: @KarlKnechtel already add the j+=1 in the else but still does not work out

Comment: @TimRoberts k += 1 is on every while loop

Comment: Do you mean that the resulting list should not contain odd numbers? Maybe you should show some sample input and expected output. Also, Google will be your friend when looking for implementations of Merge Sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be easier to sort the entire list then remove odd numbers afterwards. Something like this:

```
from random import randint
# merge sort in situ
def mergeSort(lst):
    if len(lst) > 1:
        r = len(lst) // 2
        left = lst[:r]
        right = lst[r:]

        mergeSort(left)
        mergeSort(right)

        i = j = k = 0

        while i < len(left) and j < len(right):
            if left[i] < right[j]:
                lst[k] = left[i]
                i += 1
            else:
                lst[k] = right[j]
                j += 1
            k += 1

        if (m := len(left) - i) > 0:
            lst[k:k+m] = left[i:i+m]
        else:
            m = len(right) - j
            lst[k:k+m] = right[j:j+m]

# create a list of 50 pseudo-random numbers in the range 1 to 100
lst = [randint(1, 100) for _ in range(50)]
print(lst)
mergeSort(lst)
# reconstruct the list taking only even numbers
lst = [x for x in lst if x % 2 == 0]
print(lst)
```

Comment: Why not remove them beforehand?